# FULL OUTER JOIN throwing error "wrap select in parentheses"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am having trouble with a part of my SQL call, I receive this error
 `Error: Syntax error: Each subquery argument for table-valued function calls must be enclosed in parentheses. To fix this, replace SELECT... with (SELECT...) at [32:5]`
This is at the `SELECT` after the `FULL OUTER JOIN EACH`, I'd argue that I have done that, I do not know what is wrong here so any suggestions would be much appriciated.

I am trying to create a funnel that more acurately sorts previous customers from new. There are in total 3 levels in the funnel, for "simplicity" I'll only show two.

```
SELECT
 COUNT(s0.firstHit) AS pageId1,
 SUM(s0.exit) AS pageId2,
 COUNT(s1.firstHit) AS pageId3,
 SUM(s1.exit) AS pageId4
FROM(
  SELECT
    s0.fullVisitorId,
    s0.visitId,
    s0.firstHit,
    s0.exit,
    s1.firstHit,
    s1.exit
  FROM (
    SELECT
      fullvisitorid,
      visitid,
      (SELECT MIN(hitNumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'pageId')) AS firstHit,
      (SELECT MAX(IF(isExit, 1, 0)) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'pageId')) AS exitFlag
    FROM
      `<ID>.ga_sessions_2017*`
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0601' AND '0602'
      AND 1 = 1
      AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'pageId'))
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) hits WHERE (SELECT COUNT(value) FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) custd WHERE index=20) > 0)
  AND totals.visits = 1
  GROUP BY
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId) AS s0
  FULL OUTER JOIN EACH(
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    (SELECT MIN(hitNumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, 'pageId')) AS firstHit,
    (SELECT MAX(IF(isExit, 1, 0)) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, 'pageId')) AS exitFlag
  FROM
    `<ID>.ga_sessions_2017*`
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0601' AND '0602'
    AND totals.visits = 1
  GROUP BY
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId) AS s1
ON
  s0.fullVisitorId = s1.fullVisitorId
  AND s0.visitId = s1.visitId ) s01
```

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong, and I make a living staring at SQL queries all day.  That being said, I would recommend that you take the query apart into smaller pieces and get each piece working separately.  Then build up until it breaks again.

Comment: The top most part of the query does work in itself. It is only when I add the full outer join that it is being unpleasant. I'll give it a go at making an even simpler call.

Comment: What does `EACH` do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find ways to write this query and not having the `JOIN` operations going on.

For instance:

```
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  visitid,
  (SELECT MIN(hitNumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'pageId')) AS firstFunnelHit,
  (SELECT MAX(IF(isExit, 1, 0)) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'pageId')) AS firstExitFunnelFlag,
  (SELECT MIN(hitNumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE (REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'pageId')) OR ((select count(1) from unnest(hits) h, unnest(h.customDimensions) custd where custd.index = 20) > 0)) secondFunnelHit,
  (SELECT MAX(IF(isExit, 1, 0)) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'pageId') OR ((select count(1) from unnest(hits) h, unnest(h.customDimensions) custd where custd.index = 20) > 0)) AS secondFunnelExitFlag
FROM `dataset.ga_sessions_2017*`
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0601' AND '0602'
  AND totals.visits = 1
```

Notice that in just one `SELECT` you can bring information regarding all visitors who have been in page "pageId" and also visitors who have been in this page and fired the `customDimension` on `index=20`.

For each step in your funnel analyzes you can bring new columns as results, such as the `firstFunnelHit` and `secondFunnelHit`.

By avoiding expensive `JOIN`s you can query up to teras of data and still have results in seconds.

Comment: Thanks, you are the best, this works and I learned somthing too, great!

Answer (score 0):

In the last subquery:

```
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId
    (SELECT MIN(hitNumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, 'pageId')) AS firstHit,
    (SELECT MAX(IF(isExit, 1, 0)) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, 'pageId')) AS exitFlag
  FROM
    `<ID>.ga_sessions_2017*`
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0601' AND '0602'
    AND totals.visits = 1
  GROUP BY
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId
```

it looks to me like you need a comma after `visitId` in the third line.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `EACH` keyword when using standard SQL; this is specific to legacy SQL. Remove that word and your query will probably work.

Comment: I tried that which makes it give: `Error: Each function argument is an expression, not a query. To use a query as an expression, the query must be wrapped with additional parentheses to make it a scalar subquery expression. at [35:8]`